# LNK2019 and LNK 2001 error on Visual Studio using the olc Pixel Game Console

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I'm trying to learn C++, and am very new to all of this.

I want to program a simple engine using the One Lone Coder olcPixelGameEngine.h header file for output on a window, but I can't seem to get it to work properly.

I'm using Visual Studio 2019 Community Edition, and linked the header filer through **Project -> Properties -> Configuration Properties -> C/C++ -> Additional Include Directories**

[The Error Codes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oNN6x.png):

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   LNK2019 unresolved external symbol "public: __thiscall olc::Pixel::Pixel(unsigned char,unsigned char,unsigned char,unsigned char)" (??0Pixel@olc@@QAE@EEEE@Z) referenced in function "void __cdecl olc::`dynamic initializer for 'BLACK''(void)" (??__EBLACK@olc@@YAXXZ)    3dVectorGraphics    C:\Users\[me]\source\repos\3dVectorGraphics\3dVectorGraphics\3dVectorGraphics.obj   1
```

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   LNK2001 unresolved external symbol "public: virtual bool __thiscall olc::PixelGameEngine::OnUserDestroy(void)" (?OnUserDestroy@PixelGameEngine@olc@@UAE_NXZ)    3dVectorGraphics    C:\Users\[me]\source\repos\3dVectorGraphics\3dVectorGraphics\3dVectorGraphics.obj   1
```

What should I be looking at to solve this problem? From the Microsoft docs page it seems there are a lot of possible causes, and I don't know where to start

Comment: Does the [olcPixelEngine example](https://github.com/OneLoneCoder/olcPixelGameEngine/wiki#example-olcpixelengine-hello-world) build without errors, and what's different in your code?

Comment: Thank you so much. I forgot to add the #define ```OLC_PGE_APPLICATION``` at the top, and your comment reminded me of that. It works perfectly now, thanks

Answer (score 1):

I just forgot to add `#define OLC_PGE_APPLICATION` at the top of the program, and it now magically runs perfectly. If anyone know why that is, could I get a short explanation for that please?

Comment: Most likely, the `OLC_PGE_APPLICATION` turns the header from a header-for-a-linked-library approach to a header-only library approach, where the header both declares *and also* defines the bodies of the methods that were previously missing and caused the link error.

Comment: See this [code comment](https://github.com/OneLoneCoder/olcPixelGameEngine/blob/master/olcPixelGameEngine.h#L922). It's a "code guard" for the functions defined in the `.h`.